# Get associated image (Drawable) in ImageView android

Tags: android, imageview

I have set an image to an `ImageView` control in android:

```
iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.image1);
```

I want to get this associated Drawable, looks like:

```
Drawable myDrawable = iv.getImageResource(); //wrong
```

Comment: can you elaborate.here confusion what you want.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You can get the drawable like

```
Drawable myDrawable = iv.getDrawable();
```

You can compare it with a drawable resource like

```
if(iv.getDrawable()==getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.image1)){
    //do work here
}
```

Comment: It didn't work for me either.. and yet it has the check mark.

Comment: Maybe use `#equals()` instead of `==`? Actually, not sure if Drawables can be compared like that.. Maybe there's another way (a comparator class perhaps)?

Comment: Drawables can be compared like that without any problem.

Comment: it is not working, it return false after compare it ??

Answer (score 9):

Define the Drawable first.

```
Drawable myDrawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.image1);
iv.setImageDrawable(myDrawable);
```

Comment: Just to clarify here, as the result of `getDrawable(getContext(), R.drawable.image1).getConstantState()` state value changes every time, so its not good to use getConstantState. 

Therefore this is the best answer

Answer (score 8):

Unfortunately, there is no `getImageResource()` or `getDrawableId()`. But, I created a simple workaround by using the ImageView tags.

In onCreate():

```
imageView0 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView0);
imageView1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
imageView2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView2);

imageView0.setTag(R.drawable.apple);
imageView1.setTag(R.drawable.banana);
imageView2.setTag(R.drawable.cereal);
```

Then, if you like, you can create a simple function to get the drawable id:

```
private int getImageResource(ImageView iv) {
    return (Integer) iv.getTag();
}
```

I hope this helps you, it sure made my work easier.

Comment: I am looking for solution in which the image resource on image view changes. I want to know the current resource to behave based on it. this solution won't work since we have to initialise the tag property with resource id in design time. right??

Comment: You can add or change the tag at any time. Also, depending on exactly what you are trying to do, a [ViewFlipper](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ViewFlipper.html) may be a choice to consider.

Comment: I am using an external library for downloading images and it changes the image on imageview. I didn't want to modify the library. so I implemented another solution. thanks

Answer (score 5):

use `Drawable drawable=imageview.getDrawable();`

Comment: thanks!, how can i compare it with a DrawableResource? (R.drawable.image1)

Comment: @thenosic, you can compare it. Check my answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can compare drawable resources like

```
     if (imageView.getDrawable().getConstantState() == 
        ContextCompat.getDrawable(getContext(), R.drawable.image1).getConstantState()) {
}
```

**BitmapDrawables created from the same resource will for instance share a unique -bitmap stored in their ConstantState**
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/Drawable.ConstantState

```
getResources.getDrawable is deprecated so you can use ContextCompat.getDrawable inplace of it.
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an easy approach if you can use the view's id member variable: just store the R.drawable id using v.setId().  Then get it back with v.getId().

Answer (score 0):

```
if ((holder.fav.getDrawable().getConstantState()) == context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.star_blank).getConstantState() ) {

  holder.fav.setImageDrawable(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.star_fill));

// comparison is true
}
```

//getConstantState() is the key

Answer (score 0):

getResources().getDrawable() is now deprecated, just use getDrawable(R.id.myImage);