# How can I access ImageView that was dynamically created in LinearLayout to use it source else where?

Tags: android

How can I get the source id (id.drawable.blablabla) of an ImageView that I created dynamically (like this):

```
ImageView image = new ImageView(this);
        image.setImageResource(imageId);
        image.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(size, size));
        layout.addView(image);
```

I wanna use getChildAt method on my layout if it is possible. I just need that image else where and I don't have control what image it actually is becouse they creation is based on rand. Index of that element is enough for me

**ANSWER**
I jsut find cool solution! I just add `image.setTag(imageId)` line of code to my method and then when I need rolled image I can simply use id under tag, thanks for help :)

Comment: you adding multiple images or single?

Comment: multiple in simple for loop

Comment: so what process you want to make on image means on any event of specific image or something else need more information

Comment: Idea is to create Counter Strike case opening like animation, it just random one imageView out of many created in random order. Then I show won image in another ImageView, for now I done this this way: - fill linear layout with images; - index of wanted element * image width gives me value for my animate().translationX, and thats all, I know what element I won couse I know index, right?

Comment: dint get your question please add some more code what you tried and want to achive

Comment: Hello please check my answer and tell me about your review

Answer (score 1):

I get dynamic drawable like this:

```
int id = getResources().getIdentifier("action" + String.valueOf(randomint), "drawable", getPackageName());
Drawable d = getResources().getDrawable(id);
```

And then add them to an imageview. Which you then add to a Linear layout.

Does this solve your problem?

Comment: get all children of linearlayout, check tem if they are of type imageview. Cast the child to image and get the drawable.

Answer (score 1):

```
    ImageView image = new ImageView(this);
    image.setId(1 + 28000); // Id in integer suppose we use this value where 1 is dynamic value which you wants to add in your imageview.
    image.setImageResource(imageId);
    image.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(size, size));
    layout.addView(image);
```

// Now here is code to get its id which you want in integer :

```
       image.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
              public void onClick(View arg0) {              
              System.out.println("your id" + (arg0.getId() - 28000));  
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the drawable like

```
Drawable myDrawable = iv.getDrawable();
```

You can compare it with a drawable resource like

```
if(iv.getDrawable()==getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.image1)){
    //do work here
}
```

credit https://stackoverflow.com/a/20765566/4211264